# How to do packaging in RTC on Linux platform

Tags: version-control

I am working on RTC Build and Packaging.

I set Build Engine environment on Linux platform and accessing RTC and Eclipse from Windows platform. In the actual process, the Build Engine part got success and proceed with the packaging.

But once I give create Package, I am getting this error....

```
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] running on host: akshay-VirtualBox
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] Should build occur?
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] Yes: Always build a user initiated request.
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] CRRTC3507W: Warning: An engine participant was not found for the build configuration element "Packaging Build Configuration Name".
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] CRRTC3507W: Warning: An engine participant was not found for the build configuration element "Rational Build Agent Element".
2018-10-08 11:25:41 [Jazz build engine] Invoking build participant "com.ibm.team.build.ant"
Buildfile: /home/akshay/Documents/package.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/akshay/Documents/package.xml:15: Cannot find /home/akshay/Documents/${env.BLD_TOOLKIT}/BuildToolkitTaskDefs.xml imported from /home/akshay/Documents/package.xml

Total time: 4 seconds
Build failed. Exit value was 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an Enterprise Extensions type of build (Rational Build Agent). If you are doing Java development, you do not need the RBA. Use the Jazz Build Engine, and package your jar's with ANT or Maven.

If you are doing C/C++ development, you can still use the JBE, but call Make instead. The RBA would work better if you are truly doing dependency builds.